# sum of squares of all real values of x satisfying given equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, real-numbers, substitution

If $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2+\frac{9x^2}{(x+3)^2}=27$, then sum of squares of all real values of $x$ satisfying given equation is _________.

Comment: a homework problem?

Comment: no it a sample paper question for my exam preparations.

Answer (score 1):

It's
$$x^2-\frac{6x^2}{x+3}+\frac{9x^2}{(x+3)^2}+\frac{6x^2}{x+3}=27$$ or
$$\left(x-\frac{3x}{x+3}\right)^2+\frac{6x^2}{x+3}=27$$ or
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{x+3}\right)^2+\frac{6x^2}{x+3}-27=0,$$
which gives
$$\frac{x^2}{x+3}=-9$$ or
$$\frac{x^2}{x+3}=3.$$
The first equation gives $$x^2+9x+27=0$$ or
$$(x+4.5)^2+6.75=0,$$
which is impossible.

The second case for you (use the Viete's theorem).

I got $x_1^2+x_2^2=27$.